# How to do a couchbase view query when the startkey and endkey are the same?

Tags: view, mapreduce, couchbase

Map Fuction

```
function(doc, meta) {
  if (doc.login_timestamp) {
    emit(dateToArray(doc.login_timestamp), doc.username);
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
[2011,10,10,10,10,09] “scalabl3”
[2012,12,24,17,03,59] “scalabl3”
[2013,01,01,08,22,23] “scalabl3”
[2013,01,25,10,38,01] “tgrall”
[2013,01,25,11,02,32] “jzablocki”
[2013,02,01,11,02,32] “scalabl3”
```

How do I get just the records from 2013?
I tried

```
startkey=[2013]&endkey=[2013]
```

That doesn't work because by definition results must be greater than equal the start key AND less than the end key

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is this Couchbase Server, or Couchbase Lite?

Comment: Maybe something like this? `startkey=[2013]&endkey=[2014]`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an array, you can specify arrays for start and end.  So one of two ways that should work:

```
startkey=[2013]&endkey=[2014]
```

or

```
startkey=[2013]&endkey=[2013,99]
```

In the second example, you give a value greater than any you expect to see in a valid entry.

Comment: Sure, that'll work because it's numerical. But what about when the initial value is a string e.g "some id"? How do I add 1 to that? Is there any way to get everything where the first part matches a value and not a range?

Comment: If you're talking Couchbase Lite, then you can use `inclusiveEnd` and `inclusiveStart`.  The endkey can act as a prefix, too.  So you could specify the endkey as the same as your start, or whatever, and include it.  See https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/query/query/index.html and https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html for more.